# Difference tool

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I am new to QGIS, however yesterday I had the Difference tool working and today I cannot get it working! I have followed the same method but no result. Is this common?  How can I go about making this work? I have tried to find some step by step instructions but can't find any.

Comment: Can you give us more details? What version of QGIS are you working with? What is your OS? What error you receive during the work?

Comment: I have managed to do it but only if a certain layer (not my difference layer!) is the input, when i try to do it the other way round, nothing happens. I have checked CRS and they are the same. I have tried to create two brand new layers to test it and it's taking ages to do anything.